# Как перенаправить поток ввода обратно в консоль (linux)

Tags: c++, linux

Я хочу перенаправить поток ввода обратно в консоль. В Windows можно так:

```
freopen(CON,"r",stdin).
```

Как это сделать в линуксе?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r");
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    fclose(stdin);
    //?????????????????????????????????
    string word2;
    cin >> word2;
    cout << word << " " << word2;

}
```

Ура!!! Я нашел ответ: freopen("/dev/tty","r",stdin)

Comment: вместо CON используется  STDIN / STDOUT (для ввода и для вывода)

Comment: @KoVadim то есть так freopen(STDIN,"r",stdin); ?

Comment: @KoVadim STDIN не обязан на терминал указывать (pipe, файл). Можно открыть терминал, если не isatty.

Comment: в таком случае теоретически может и терминала вообще не существовать

Comment: @jfs а что ты предлагаешь?

Comment: Приведите пример кода в то я непонятливый

Comment: @KoVadim: подумав, не ясно что вы имели в виду. Если вы имели в виду `STDIN_FILENO` вместо `STDIN`, тогда нельзя в freopen передать (это fd, а не имя) -- можно dup2 использовать для перенаправления. Если вы имели в виду `/dev/stdin`, то это может иногда работать. И как автор упомянул, для работы с терминалом, можно `/dev/tty` открыть (для некоторых вещей может `/dev/tty0` понадобится).

Comment: @neo: если думаете что нашли решение, то не стоит его в вопрос помещать, опубликуйте ответ как ответ (см. кнопку ниже "Отправить ответ") -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs хорошо спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ:

```
freopen("/dev/tty","r",stdin)
```

Comment: Вы нашли очередной хак, а не ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего - не перенаправлять поток в файл, тогда и перенаправлять его обратно не придется.

Для чтения данных из файла можно использовать класс ifstream:

```
#include <fstream>

// ...

std::ifstream file ("input.txt", std::ifstream::in);
std::string word;
file >> word;
file.close(); // можно не делать если область жизни переменной file заканчивается

std::string word2;
std::cin >> word2;
```

Comment: даже если буквальное решение не является хорошей идеей во многих случаях, ответ должен содержать ответ на вопрос как он написан (хотя стоит конечно упомянуть лучшие в обычных ситуациях варианты). В тему, мета-обсуждение: [Как избежать буквальных ответов на очевидно неграмотные вопросы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4134/23044)